# Object with dynamic atributes from table Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script

I have a table where in firs row are names of columns (variable number of them) and I want to convert this table into object in javascript.

Example table can looks like:

```
Ticket  | Created    | State
--------+------------+-------
#102314 | 2018-11-12 |  1
#102315 | 2018-11-14 |  5
```

And if I wanted to put it in object it will looks like:

```
var toReturn = [];
var table = [['Ticket', 'Created', 'State'],
            ['#102314', 2018-11-12, 1],
            ['#102315', 2018-11-14, 5]];
           /*This is how i recieve data from google Spreadsheets*/
for(var k = 1; k < table.length; k++) {
  toReturn.push({'Ticket': table[k][0],
                 'Created': table[k][1],
                 'State': table[k][2]});
} //This is working for me

// But I'm trying something like this and it not working
for(var k = 1; k < table.length; k++) {
    toReturn.push({table[0][0]: table[k][0],
                   table[0][1]: table[k][1],
                   table[0][2]: table[k][2]});
}
```

And the ultimate goal is to create object with all attributes from table independent on how many columns are in the table.

Comment: My bad, I updated the code..

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a second loop which iterates over the column headers and adds them one at a time to a temporary object which is then pushed into `toReturn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way could be to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> The  `reduce()`  method executes a  **reducer**  function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.
>
> The  **reducer**  function is fed four parameters:
>
> 1. Accumulator (acc)
> 2. Current Value (cur)
> 3. Current Index (idx)
> 4. Source Array (src)
>
> Your  **reducer**  function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.

```js
var table = [
  ['Ticket', 'Created', 'State'],
  ['#102314', '2018-11-12', 1],
  ['#102315', '2018-11-14', 5]
];

var transformedTable = table.reduce(function(result, currentRow, rowIndex) {
  // skip the "header row"
  if (rowIndex === 0) {
    return result;
  }

  // create the actual row from the "header row" and the values of the current row
  var row = table[0].reduce(function(resultRow, caption, captionIndex) {
    resultRow[caption] = currentRow[captionIndex];
    return resultRow;
  }, {})

  result.push(row);

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(transformedTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is to make to loops as Andreas said, and get the key names on each loop.

Something like that:

```
for (var k = 1; k < table.length; k++){
    obj = {}
    for (var j = 0; j < table[k].length; j++){
        obj[table[0][j]] = table[k][j]
    }
    toReturn.push(obj)
}
```